# How to Produce These Old-Style Text Dividers with PDFLATEX

Tags: graphics, pdftex, includegraphics

[image]I came across these text dividers in an old book:
[image]

Does anyone know if either of these are already defined in LATEX? If so, where may I find them. If they aren't, how may they be replicated using PDFLATEX? Thank you.

Comment: The way I see it, there are two options: use a font that contains such dividers (I have used e.g. Hoefler Fleuron in the past, if memory serves) or (if you can’t use either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX probably your only option) make your own, as it were. Using `TikZ` this should be possible, and the `pgfornament` (CTAN) package will give you a head start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Ingmar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/26614/ingmar) suggests, one of many options is to draw the separators with `tikz`. It's better to use a macro to avoid repeating code too. I can't see your picture well enough, but you can get an idea and change the following example as you need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage   {lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage   {tikz}

\newcommand{\oldsep}
{%
  \begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \draw[-latex] (-1,0) -- (-0.025,0);
  \draw[-latex] ( 1,0) -- ( 0.025,0);
  \draw[fill=white] (0,0) circle (0.075);
  \end{tikzpicture}\end{center}
}

\newcommand{\othersep}
{%
  \begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \draw (-1,0) -- (1,0);
  \fill[rotate=45] (-0.075,-0.075) rectangle (0.075,0.075);
  \end{tikzpicture}\end{center}
}

\newcommand{\onemore}
{%
  \begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \draw (-1,0) -- (1,0);
  \foreach\i in {-1,1}
    \fill [x=\i cm,rotate=-45*\i] (0.05,0.05) rectangle (0.15,0.15);
  \draw[fill=white] (0,0) circle (0.075);
  \end{tikzpicture}\end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\oldsep
\lipsum[2]
\othersep
\lipsum[3]
\onemore
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** I made a third separator, because the original picture has very low quality and it's possible that I'm not seeing it correctly.

Comment: Looks nice, +1. I am also not sure what the picture in the question shows exactly but I think the upper one has Diamond arrows instead of regular arrows.

Comment: @Marijn, thanks!! You're probably right, so I made an edit with another separator.

Comment: I was thinking of `\draw[-Diamond] (-1,0) -- (-0.025,0);` or `\draw[-Turned Square]` with `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` - but your new version also works of course :)

Comment: @Juan Castano Thank you very much for posting this answer.