# Adding a Tikz-Produced Text Separator to the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, diagrams

This question is an extension of the one posed in [How to Produce These Old-Style Text Dividers with PDFLATEX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605679/how-to-produce-these-old-style-text-dividers-with-pdflatex)

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\oldsep}
{%
  \begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \draw[-latex] (-1,0) -- (-0.025,0);
  \draw[-latex] ( 1,0) -- ( 0.025,0);
  \draw[fill=white] (0,0) circle (0.075);
  \end{tikzpicture}\end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\oldsep
\tableofcontents
%\addtocontents{toc}{ $\oldsep$}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following Tikz-produced text divider:

[image]

I would like to be able to call it into the TOC to be used as a text separator; however, the line that I have commented out in the code, for some reason, is not correct.

Question: Can someone suggest how I may modify the code so that I may call the said picture into the TOC when I want to? Thank you.

Comment: If you are going to be using this a lot, you should put it into a savebox instead of a macro.

Comment: @John Kormylo Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to protect it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\oldsep}
{%
  \begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \draw[-latex] (-1,0) -- (-0.025,0);
  \draw[-latex] ( 1,0) -- ( 0.025,0);
  \draw[fill=white] (0,0) circle (0.075);
  \end{tikzpicture}\end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\oldsep
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\oldsep}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I've also taken this opportunity to learn a little about the \protect command. Thanks again.